# Error 438 when using GetConversation on a mail item

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to export all e-mails in a shared inbox to excel. I'm specifically interested in how many conversations I've had, rather than all e-mails I've received.

I'm getting the `438 error`  on the `Set conv = Item.GetConversation()` line:

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

This implies that Item doesn't support GetConversation, even though it is a function for a MailItem.

```
    Public Sub ExportToExcel()
        Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
        Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
        Dim SubFolder As Object
        Dim MailFolder As Object
        Dim SharedInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim objRecip As Outlook.Recipient

        Dim Item As Object
        Dim conv As Object
        Dim store As Outlook.Store

        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim i As Long
        Dim ArrHeader As Variant

        On Error GoTo MsgErr

        Set objOL = Application
        Set objNS = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set objRecip = objNS.CreateRecipient("sharedmailbox@outlook.com")
        Set SharedInbox = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecip, olFolderInbox)

        Set MailFolder = SharedInbox.Folders("Archive").Folders("Sub")


        ArrHeader = Array("Category", "Date Sent", "Subject", "Mails in conversation")

        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add


        xlWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").resize(1, UBound(ArrHeader) + 1).Value = ArrHeader

        For Each SubFolder In MailFolder.Folders
            For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
                If (Item.Class = olMail) Then
                    store = SubFolder.store

                    If (store.IsConversationEnabled) Then
                        Set conv = Item.GetConversation()

                        If (conv <> Null) Then
                            xlWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = SubFolder.Name
                            xlWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = Item.ReceivedTime
                            xlWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, "C").Value = Item.Subject
                            xlWB.Worksheets(1).Cells(i + 1, "D").Value = conv.GetTable().getrows()
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next Item
        Next SubFolder

        xlWB.Worksheets(1).Cells.EntireColumn.Autofit

    MsgErr_Exit:
        Set emailSourceFolder = Nothing
        Set emailDestFolder = Nothing
        Set objNS = Nothing
        Set objOL = Nothing
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
        Set MailFolder = Nothing
        Set SharedInbox = Nothing
        Set objRecip = Nothing
        Set Item = Nothing
        Set conv = Nothing
        Set Store = Nothing
        Set xlWB = Nothing
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set i = Nothing
        Set ArrHeader = Nothing

        Exit Sub

    '// Error information
    MsgErr:
        MsgBox "An unexpected Error has occurred." _
             & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
             & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
             , vbCritical, "Error!"
        Resume MsgErr_Exit

    End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the user-type error handling `On Error GoTo MsgErr` while in development. Edit the question with that line commented and update the line that causes the error.

Comment: The missing `Set` in the line `store = SubFolder.store` should generate an error before reaching the line `Set conv = Item.GetConversation()`.